# Run simple Python script periodically on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I would like to host a python script on Google Cloud, so it can store the data from said script on my Google Cloud Sql database which is connected to Google Data Studio. However, the documentation is way to complicated for my.

I just want to host a simple script that runs each week.

Please note that I definitely need to run my script on Google Cloud so alternative options like PythonAnywhere are not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your python script as a cron job. It can run periodically at the required time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thanks! But the problem in all the documentation is that they all talk abount python APPS and not a simple script. Does that make a difference?